# Amazon s3Exception bad request and location constraint in hadoop s3a

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, qubole

Does location constraint require extra permission policy for hadoop s3a?

I am seeing

```
Exception in thread "main" com.qubole.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request;
```

For all buckets that have

```
{
    "LocationConstraint": "us-west-1"
}
```

in qubole hadoop

but not for buckets without location constraint

```
{
    "LocationConstraint": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

never seen that, but I've never played with that restriction. What could be the cause is that the client is defaulting to talk to S3 through the default central endpoint, not the us west one.

see [s3a troubleshooting](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#a.E2.80.9CBad_Request.E2.80.9D_exception_when_working_with_AWS_S3_Frankfurt.2C_Seoul.2C_or_other_.E2.80.9CV4.E2.80.9D_endpoint)

set `fs.s3a.endpoint` to the relevant one [listed here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Using_Per-Bucket_Configuration_to_access_data_round_the_world)

if this works -update this question...it'll be something to update the s3 docs with then